# Bulk email sending issue with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, bulk-email

I'm trying to send about 200 emails from Godaddy's relay server, when I do this error message pops up

> Exceeded storage allocation. The server response was: 5.2.0 zLajfQofP2ka6 :: ded :: Message rejected for spam or virus content :: Please include this entire message when contacting support :: v=2.3 cv=Ro0U0xuK c=1 sm=1 tr=0 p=jyZi1tzBAAAA:8 a=nUny5+uFbDM6FTXWPkDtjg==:117 a=nUny5+uFbDM6FTXWPkDtjg==:17 a=kj9zAlcOel0A:10 a=3g80flMcAAAA:8 a=1SDZlyROrrQHGVcCO2IA:9 a=nDNGZ0tykMefl_73:21 a=_W_S_7VecoQA:10 a=CjuIK1q_8ugA:10 a=gZNFefrQUiWykQekTDV7:22 :: 100.00

I've contacted Godaddy and they told me that they have a limit of 50 emails per 2 mins, I've tried that and it's not working.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: There seems to be **three issues** here: (1) exceeded send rate limit, (2) exceeded disk allocation, (3) a detected virus in your outbound mail. Ask tech support which of these you are getting.

Comment: I've asked them and they are saying that 50 emails per 2 mins is okay, but i've tried it and it's NOT, is there is any way that i can do it from my code to overcome this issue??and is this issue is popular with bulk emails??